# How to force commit a snapshot on vmware ESX virtual machine?

Tags: vmware-esx, snapshot

I have a virtual machine in ESX with snapshot; unfortunately when trying to commit the snapshots, vmware somehow lost track of the whole structure; the virtual machine got one week back, while on the disk there are still the files with the snapshot data (esx completely lost track of these files). Is there a way to force commit of these snapshot files into the virtual machine?

Answer (score 3):

I find myself in this same situation from time to time as well. What usually works for me (and what is one of the troubleshooting steps VMware support would walk you through) is to create a new snapshot and then do a "delete all". That should merge all of the delta files back into the base disk.